# Intercept value read from registry

Tags: c++, winapi, registry, hook

I'm loading a third party DLL that reads some of its own settings from HKCU, and I want to change its behaviour by altering a couple of values that it reads.

Assuming that it only reads when it is first loaded, I could write the changed values to the registry, then load the DLL then change the values back again. But for a brief period of time this would also affect any other process that might load the same DLL.

Is there a way to alter the value that it will read within just my own process?

Comment: This seems frought with complication.  Even if the values are read only once, it'll be a finite time after it loads.  So there will always be a window within which something else could load the DLL as well, n'est pas?

Comment: I'd just rename the DLL and then use an editor to change the strings in the DLL.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to alter the value that it will read within just my own process?

Use a detour of the Win32 API function that the DLL calls to read from the registry. There are many detour libraries available that can facilitate this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use firefox's [windowsdllinteceptor](http://lxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/xpcom/build/nsWindowsDllInterceptor.h), which is a header only dll interceptor for api hook.

Sample code for alter the vml tag value:

```
typedef DWORD(__stdcall *NtQueryKeyType)(
    HANDLE  KeyHandle,
    int KeyInformationClass,
    PVOID  KeyInformation,
    ULONG  Length,
    PULONG  ResultLength);
NtQueryKeyType sNtQueryKeyPtr = NULL;

std::wstring GetKeyPathFromKKEY(HKEY key)
{
    std::wstring keyPath;
    if (sNtQueryKeyPtr != NULL) {
        DWORD size = 0;
        DWORD result = 0;
        result = sNtQueryKeyPtr(key, 3, 0, 0, &size);
        if (result == STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL) {
            size = size + 2;
            wchar_t* buffer = new (std::nothrow) wchar_t[size / sizeof(wchar_t)]; // size is in bytes
            if (buffer != NULL)
            {
                result = sNtQueryKeyPtr(key, 3, buffer, size, &size);
                if (result == STATUS_SUCCESS)
                {
                    buffer[size / sizeof(wchar_t)] = L'\0';
                    keyPath = std::wstring(buffer + 2);
                }
                delete[] buffer;
            }
        }
    }
    return keyPath;
}

DWORD __stdcall VWMLNtQueryKey(
    HANDLE  KeyHandle,
    int KeyInformationClass,
    PVOID  KeyInformation,
    ULONG  Length,
    PULONG  ResultLength) {
    auto str = GetKeyPathFromKKEY((HKEY)KeyHandle);
    if (!str.empty() && base::StringProcess::endsWith(str, L"Internet Explorer\\Version Vector"))
        return STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;
    return sNtQueryKeyPtr(KeyHandle, KeyInformationClass, KeyInformation, Length, ResultLength);
}

base::WindowsDllInterceptor ntHook;
ntHook.Init("ntdll.dll");
if (!ntHook.AddHook("NtQueryKey", reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(&VWMLNtQueryKey),
    (void**)&sNtQueryKeyPtr)) {
    removeVMLTags(&html);
}
```